# How to test if user is redirectoed to error page when an exception occurs?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

I am trying to write a unit test to test one of my controller's actions `ShareWorkbook`. The test should check if the user is sent to the generic error page (defined in `Startup.cs`) if an exception occurs in the above action. However, at the moment but my unit tests fail because of my hard coded exception. I know that my test checks that the user is redirected to the error page but that exception breaks the unit test (see exception below) Is there a way on getting around this so that the exception is ignored and the test passes?

That is my **HomeController** with the action I am trying to test:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
...

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult ShareWorkbook(string emails, string title, string workbookId)
    {
        var emailStrArr = Regex.Split(emails, Constants.SplitPattern).ToList();

        var workbookShareModel = new WorkbookShareModel
        {
            WorkbookId = workbookId,
            Title = title,
            Emails = emailStrArr
        };

        // check to see if the 'WorkbookShareModel' is valid (takes into account its property DataAnnotation)
        if (TryValidateModel(workbookShareModel))
        {
            try
            {
                ShareWorkbook(workbookShareModel);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogException(e, e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        // return no content to avoid page refresh
        return NoContent();
    }

    private void ShareWorkbook(WorkbookShareModel workbookShareModel)
    {
       // MOCK SERVICE
        _workbookManagementService.ShareWorkbook(workbookShareModel);
    }
}
```

Currently, I have a hardcoded exception that I've added in my `MockService`:

```
public class MockManagementService : IManagementService
{
    public void ShareWorkbook(WorkbookShareModel sharedWorkbook)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedWorkbook.WorkbookId))
            throw new Exception("Couldn't share workbook");
    }
}
```

That the exception I am getting (expected):

```
System.Exception : Couldn't share workbook
   at Project.Test.Services.MockManagementService.ShareWorkbook(WorkbookShareModel sharedWorkbook) in D:\_JustCodeHere\Apps\ProjectCore\ProjectCore.Test\Services\MockManagementService.cs:line 27
```

That is my unit test:

```
public class HomeControllerTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void error_page_is_shown_if_exception_occurs_during_workbook_sharing_process()
    {
        // Arrange
        var workbookService = new MockManagementService();
        var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger>();
        var controller = new HomeController(null, null, workbookService, mockLogger.Object);
        controller.ObjectValidator = new TestingObjectValidator();

        // Act
        // passing 'null' for the workbookId parameter raises an exception
        var result = controller.ShareWorkbook("test@email.com", "workbook title", null);

        // Assert
        var redirectToActionResult = Assert.IsType<RedirectToActionResult>(result);
        Assert.Equal("Error", redirectToActionResult.ActionName);
    }
}
```

This is how I got my error page setup:

```
public class Startup
{
    ...
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried `TestServer` and integration tests instead? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: That is a good point as my test could be considered an integration test as I am testing more than 1 thing here. However, I am still unsure how to get my test to pass even when there is an exception being raised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing the `throw;` call in my controller's action with `return RedirectToAction("Error");`. That allows me to unit test that the user is redirected to the right page like that:

```
public void error_page_is_shown_if_exception_occurs_during_workbook_sharing_process()
{
    // Arrange
    var emails = "test@email.com";
    var title = "";

    // Act
    // passing 'null' for the workbookId parameter raises an exception
    var result = _controller.ShareWorkbook(emails, title, null);

    // Assert
    var redirectToActionResult = Assert.IsType<RedirectToActionResult>(result);
    Assert.Equal("Error", redirectToActionResult.ActionName);
}
```